# What is the replacement tool for auth-client-config in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ldap

I am following the [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication) to setup LDAP authentication for an Ubuntu Focal (20.04) client.

One of the steps is to execute the command `sudo auth-client-config -t nss -p lac_ldap`.  Supposedly this utility is provided by the `ldap-auth-client` package.  However it seems it was removed in Ubuntu Focal and later.

What is the replacement command to configure `/etc/nsswitch.conf` without having to manually edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and did not find the exact issue.

But here is a workaround if used in scripts. Use sed.

```bash
sed -E 's/^passwd:\s+.*/passwd: files systemd ldap/g' -i /etc/nsswitch.conf
sed -E 's/^group:\s+.*/group: files systemd ldap/g' -i /etc/nsswitch.conf
sed -E 's/^shadow:\s+.*/shadow: files systemd ldap/g' -i /etc/nsswitch.conf
```